# PHP json decoder string

Tags: php, json

anyone can help to decode this?

var_dump

```
 sring(56441) "{"success":{"message":"PDF \u0444\u0430\u0439\u043b\u0430 \u0435 \u0433\u0435\u043d\u0435\u0440\u0438\u0440\u0430\u043d \u0443\u0441\u043f\u0435\u0448\u043d\u043e!","name":"invoice-0000000001.pdf","data":"JVBERi0xLjQKMSAwIG9iago8PAovVGl0bGUgKP7\/BCQEMAQ6BEIEQwRABDAAICEWADAAMAAwADAAMAAwADAAMA","type":"application\/pdf"}}"
```

I need to get "data" from this code.

Comment: what's the variable called?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$data='{"success":{"message":"PDF \u0444\u0430\u0439\u043b\u0430 \u0435 \u0433\u0435\u043d\u0435\u0440\u0438\u0440\u0430\u043d \u0443\u0441\u043f\u0435\u0448\u043d\u043e!","name":"invoice-0000000001.pdf","data":"JVBERi0xLjQKMSAwIG9iago8PAovVGl0bGUgKP7\/BCQEMAQ6BEIEQwRABDAAICEWADAAMAAwADAAMAAwADAAMA","type":"application\/pdf"}}';


$data=json_decode($data,true);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data['success']['data']);
```

It's a simple json that you need to make it an array and access it as a normal array. The output is the *data* field you asked:

```
JVBERi0xLjQKMSAwIG9iago8PAovVGl0bGUgKP7/BCQEMAQ6BEIEQwRABDAAICEWADAAMAAwADAAMAAwADAAMA
```

Comment: Sorry! Didn't mean to!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you only need to `json_decode()` that string and you have your result:

```
<?php
$input = '{"success":{"message":"PDF \u0444\u0430\u0439\u043b\u0430 \u0435 \u0433\u0435\u043d\u0435\u0440\u0438\u0440\u0430\u043d \u0443\u0441\u043f\u0435\u0448\u043d\u043e!","name":"invoice-0000000001.pdf","data":"JVBERi0xLjQKMSAwIG9iago8PAovVGl0bGUgKP7\/BCQEMAQ6BEIEQwRABDAAICEWADAAMAAwADAAMAAwADAAMA","type":"application\/pdf"}}';
$output = json_decode($input);
print_r($output->success->data);
```

> JVBERi0xLjQKMSAwIG9iago8PAovVGl0bGUgKP7/BCQEMAQ6BEIEQwRABDAAICEWADAAMAAwADAAMAAwADAAMA